# ImageSource from 3 IntPtr

Tags: c#, wpf, pointers, imagesource

I get three IntPtr's to the arrays of the RGB channels from an external library.
At the moment I merge the three arrays to one and create an ImageSource from the new array.

But the images can be really huge (at the moment up to 8000 x 4000 px), so the conversion of the data, which are already laying in the memory takes too long.

Is there a way to use these pointers to show the image in a canvas without copying? I.e. a derived class of ImageSource with costum OnRender method or something else?

I didn't found anything belongs to my problem.

**Update:**
My current code looks like this:

```
int unmapByes = Math.Abs(stride) - (width * 3);
        byte* _ptrR = (byte*)ptrR;
        byte* _ptrG = (byte*)ptrG;
        byte* _ptrB = (byte*)ptrB;
        BitmapSource bmpsrc = null;
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            bmpsrc = BitmapSource.Create(width,
                                                  height,
                                                  96,
                                                  96,
                                                  PixelFormats.Bgr24,
                                                  null,
                                                  new byte[bytes],
                                                  stride);
        });
        BitmapBuffer bitmapBuffer = new BitmapBuffer(bmpsrc);
        byte* buffer = (byte*)bitmapBuffer.BufferPointer;


        Parallel.For(0, bytes / 3 - height, (offset) =>
        {
            int i = offset * 3 + (((offset + 1) / width)) * unmapByes;
            *(buffer + i) = *(_ptrB + offset);
            *(buffer + i + 1) = *(_ptrG + offset);
            *(buffer + i + 2) = *(_ptrR + offset);
        });
        return bmpsrc;
```

Comment: It is the most awkward format you could get and completely incompatible with supported pixel formats.  Having to copy a hundred megabytes is inevitable and going to take a while.  Shop for another library or use a telephone.

Comment: I do not know what you're working. But the most high performance image processing libraries working with this type of images. Also the most line cameras give you those 3 Pointers to the arrays. Why do you think I'm asking for a solution? Because I have no other choice. So please take your telephone and do something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The right answer is:**

Get rid of computations in the loop, which have high costs. In this case it is the division. Computations with high costs are every computation which is not in the instruction set of the CPU.

The second one is, that a Parallel.For loop can increase the speed, but only if every Thread of the loop has a bigger amount of work. Otherwise the costs for the handling are too high.

So now I changed my code and use a Parallel.For loop for each line and an inner for loop for each pixel in this line.

Now I can convert an image with the size of 8000x4000 24rgb in 32ms (on my system I can say 1 Megapixel = 1ms).

For the future: Everyone who has a question wants to know, why his question was voted down. If you don't know the answer or only write bull***t, stop it.

Answer (score 0):

WPF image sources are actually textures residing on the GPU, so they have to have very specific formats. You won't get by with your three arrays in this world.

However, 8000x4000 is only 32MB (times color bytes), that's nothing to copy around in RAM. If you really profiled your slowdown to be about this, I'd wager you're doing something wrong (using `List<>` or similar growable arrays instead of preallocating the whole buffer, redoing the computation more than once etc.)

As one optimizing tip off the top of my head, I suggest not using the naive implementation with 3 pointers advancing at the same time, do one array at a time to preserve it in your L1 cache.

Comment: I have to reorder the data. So R[0] goes to Res[0], G[0] => Res[1], B[0] => Res[2] and so on. So I have my loop goes for 32.000.000 times. Obviously its not 32 MB. It's 96 MB (for each channel 32 MB.

Comment: Is there a question there?

Comment: What do you mean with "do one array at a time to preserve it in your L1 cache."? I added my current code, so you could help me to optimize it? I'm at a loss here. Can I make it faster?

Comment: Sure, *get rid of the* `Parallel.For`, that's not a CPU bound operation, you're just making it a lot slower. And what I mean by that is copy the arrays one byte at a time, incrementing the destination pointer (yes, use pointers) by 4 at a time.